# Sequel ORM usage

Tags: ruby, postgresql, orm, sequel

I am currently doing a small pet project involving web programming stuff using
Ruby. I am new to web programming, MVC, ORM and so on, so lots of hurdles here.

Anyway, I have difficulties using [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) as the ORM.

I already have a PostgreSQL database running
(created without using Sequel whatsoever, I just used a plain PostgreSQL command), but 
I don't know where/how to start using Sequel as the ORM.

I know how to connect to a PostgreSQL database using Sequel and then what?

It's been a frustrating time for a while as I am stuck in this problem.
The documentation in the website is kind of overwhelming for me. Trying an IRC channel resulted in no answers..

My first goal is to make a simple Ruby script that is able to update a table in PostgreSQL from a CSV file using Sequel as a ORM.

I desperately need some enlightenment.

Comment: I think your question is too broad. What exactly puzzled you in the Sequel documentation? I think the README there is extremely well-writen, both for beginners and, as a reference, for experienced users.

Comment: how you coming on this? The Sequel cheat-sheet and the README should get you connected easily.

Comment: @the Tin Man, Currently I am able to use sequel ( still in noob stage) after perusing over and over of the doc until I get that aha moment...with lots of trial and error and frustration,lol. I look at this question again now and it looks silly i feel embarassed. Sorry if there's no accepted answer here.

Comment: Progress is good. Sequel is awesome and the AHA! moment comes faster than with some tools. Remember that Sequel makes it really easy to work with datasets and that modeling isn't necessarily the easiest/fastest course. Sequel and datasets and SQL are a great starting point, then add in using methods with datasets, then start modeling. Also, the [Sequel-talk mail list](http://groups.google.com/group/sequel-talk) is another source for Sequel Q&A. Also, feel free to update your original question with sample code. We'll try helping.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) and [HAML](http://haml.info/) as a MVC combo.

It's easy to get Sinatra up and running.

Use HAML or Erubis for the views; I personally prefer HAML because it's very succinct.

Sequel is nicely documented and is my personal preference for an ORM because it's flexible and lets me build classes that map directly to the database schema and give me full relationships, or use the datasets for quick and easy database access.

Oh, regarding using Sequel to update data in a Postgres table - it's easy. Show what code you've got already and I'm sure we can get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I think that the key thing about Sequel (especially compared to other ORMs) is that it's really about datasets, and mapping tables to model classes is strictly optional.

Comment: Yes, most definitely I like the fact that table to model mapping is optional. It really speeds up development for quick 'n dirty tools.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to learn everything you need is with a good book that walks through the introduction of all these things. I highly recommend "[Agile Web Development With Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)". It will teach you everything you need to know.

Comment: I don't think it's very useful for Sequel?

Comment: Rails is still very opinionated about how to do things, so I think a more-gentle approach to learning Ruby, MVC, ORM would be Sinatra as it works very well for simple projects, integrates easily with Sequel, ActiveRecord, DataMapper or even DBI.

Comment: mladen - you're right. i wasn't paying close enough attention when i replied. i think Greg's answer is probably more appropriate.

Comment: I do agree that "Agile Web Development With Rails" is a good book once someone has learned the Ruby/MVC/ORM basics. Rails is a great platform and knowledge of how it works is a good job skill.